# Error in binding: No implementation was bound - Guice

Tags: java, guice

I’m trying to use Guice to solve dependency. I’ve read through tutorials and examples, but I still can’t figure out why I keep getting this error:

```
No implementation for com.edit.owl.persistence.PersistentStore<com.edit.common.domain.Foo> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=FooPersistence) was bound. while locating com.edit.owl.persistence.PersistentStore<com.edit.common.domain.Foo> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=FooPersistence)
for parameter 0 at com.edit.owl.service.FooService.<init>(FooService.java:17)while locating com.edit.owl.service.FooService
for parameter 0 at com.edit.owl.resource.DistributionListResource.<init>(ListResource.java:36)while locating com.edit.owl.resource.ListResource
```

So, basically, the structure of the code is as follow:

Entity: foo

•   fooService

```
@Singleton
public class FooService implements PersistentStore<Foo> {
private final PersistentStore<Foo> fooDAO;

@Inject
public FooService (@Named("fooPersistence")PersistentStore<Foo> fooRepository) {
    this.fooDAO = fooRepository;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Foo create(Foo foo) {
    return fooDAO .create(foo);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Foo update(Foo foo) {
    return fooDAO.update(foo);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Foo findById(Long Id) {
    return fooDAO.findById(Id);
}
}
```

•   PersistentStore
defines create, update and delete for generic datatype E
•   FooResource
client application which calls FooService

I have implemented binding in

•   FooModule

```
public class FooModuleimplements Module {
  public void configure(final Binder binder) {
     binder.bind(FooResource.class);
  }
}
```

•   PersistenceModule

```
public class PersistenceModule extends AbstractModule {
private final String persistenceUnit;

public PersistenceModule(String persistenceUnit) {
    this.persistenceUnit = persistenceUnit;
}

@Override
protected void configure() {
    install(new JpaPersistModule(persistenceUnit));
    bind(JpaInitializer.class).asEagerSingleton();

    bind(new TypeLiteral<PersistentStore<Foo>>() {
    }).to(new TypeLiteral<Foo>() {
    });

}
```

}

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have put the following line of code inside the FooResource class:   @Inject
    public FooResource(Foo Service fooService) {
        this.fooService= fooService;
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the PersistenceModule you bind the PersistenceStore without annotation. In the constructor of the FooService you ask for a dependency annotated with @Named("fooPersistence").

Either use the annotations in both the binding and the injection point or remove them.

By the way:
Prefere onami persist if you have the chance. It fixes some known bugs in guice persist (which is abandoned).