# Using Guice: No implementation bounded

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

I am new to Guice. I using Guice in conjunction with AWS SWF. My current structure in as below:

MainClass:

```
 class MainClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ClientModule(param1, param2));
    injector = injector.createChildInjector(injector.getInstance(TestModule.class));
   }
 }
```

TestModule:

```
 class TestModule extends AbstractModule {

  @override
  protected void configure() {
  // create SWF service object
  // Register Workflow worker and Activity worker

   TempWorkflowClientExternalFactory fac = TempClientExternalFactoryImpl(swf_service, domain);
     bind(TempWorkflowClientExternalFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("ABC")).toInstance(fac);  
  }
}
```

Definition to class where I want to use it:

```
 class Test {

  @Inject
  @Named("ABC")
  TempWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl fac;


   public void method() {

    TempWorkflowClientExternal temp = fac.getClient("123");
    temp.callWorkflowMethod()       // This method is defined in SWF Workflow Activity class 
   }
}
```

However on execution I get the below error:

`No implementation for <packageName>.TempWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=ABC) was bound`

I need the same object to be returned wherever TempWorkflowClientExternalFactory is injected.
I tried looking up at Guice wiki/FAQ. Unfortunately I think I overlooking something or have misunderstood some concept.

If instead of binding, I use the below code in `configure` method after creating the `fac` object, my application works as expected.

```
 TempWorkflowClientExternal temp = fac.getClient("123");
 temp.callWorkflowMethod()
```

However when I try to bind, it fails.

Update: 
If I perform the binding without the `annotatedWith`, the program executes but I can observe that binding is not done correctly as the `fac` object in `Test` class gets instantiated with default constructor and not the object I want to associate with

Additional Detail: TempWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl, TempWorkflowClientExternalFactory, TempWorkflowClientExternal are also autogenerated classes by AWS-SWF. I cannot modify their constructors or add any annotations in those classes. 
Test.method() will be invoked by when certain business logic criteria is met.

Can someone please assist how to resolve the error?

Comment: How do you construct the `Injector`? Is your `TestModule` actually installed in the injector? It would help if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah I have installed the TestModule in injector. Since code contains connection with AWS SWF with credentials, I cannot post complete example. I have replaced connection code with comment indicating same. Everything else is as in the code. I have also updated the question towards the end which mentions the auto-generated classes I am trying to bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bind(TempClientExternalFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("ABC"))
    .toInstance(fac);
```

At this point, Guice is aware of one key: `@Named("ABC") TempClientExternalFactory`. No Impl is bound.

```
@Inject
@Named("ABC")
TempClientExternalFactoryImpl fac;
```

Here, however, you don't request the `Factory`, you request the `FactoryImpl`. Guice doesn't know how to provide it, so it tells you:

> No implementation for `<packageName>.TempWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl` annotated with `@com.google.inject.name.Named(value=ABC)` was bound.

---

You have, as far as I can tell, 3 options:

1. Request the Factory, not the FactoryImpl. This is the best simple solution, because it helps you with the Guice/OOP best-practice of coding to the interface, not the implementation. You can replace the Factory in tests with any implementation, including one from a mocking framework.

   ```
   @Inject
   @Named("ABC")
   TempClientExternalFactory fac;
   ```
2. Bind the `@Named("ABC") FactoryImpl` to the instance, and then bind the `@Named("ABC") Factory` to the `@Named("ABC") FactoryImpl`. This is a good solution in the unlikely event that you want your classes to distinguish between requesting the interface and requesting the implementation *even if* they resolve to the same class right now. Otherwise, it may lead to confusing or inconsistent code, because both interface and impl will be available through the graph.

   ```
   bind(TempClientExternalFactoryImpl.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("ABC"))
       .toInstance(fac);
   bind(TempClientExternalFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("ABC"))
       .to(Key.get(TempClientExternalFactoryImpl.class, Names.named("ABC"));
   ```
3. Abstract away the factories if the real dependency you need to provide is TempWorkflowClientExternal and the factory interface/impl is unlikely to change or be called directly. Dependency injection and factory patterns can have overlapping responsibilities, so rather than using Guice to return a factory, you can use Guice to return the right implementation.

   None of that is to say that Guice shouldn't ever return a factory; if your parameter `"123"` is likely to change then it's exactly right to have Guice return a factory. If that parameter is universal across your codebase, though, you can abstract it away into your Guice Provider.

   ```
   bind(TempWorkflowClientExternal.class).toProvider(
       new Provider<TempWorkflowClientExternal>() {
     TempClientExternalFactory fac = new TempClientExternalFactoryImpl(null, null);
     return fac.getClient("123");
   });
   ```

   ...or...

   ```
   @Provides TempWorkflowClientExternal getExternalFactory() {
     TempClientExternalFactory fac = new TempClientExternalFactoryImpl(null, null);
     return fac.getClient("123");
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi @Jeff,  Thanks for your response. I tried both the first two approached. I wanted to go by first approach if possible as I would later need to do testing by mocking. Anyways, neither of approach worked. When I tried the first apporach, I got the error `No implementation for <packageName>.TempWorkflowClientExternalFactory annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=ABC) was bound` . Same for second approach as well. Please let me know if you want any more information from me

Comment: @alwaysANewbie Can you please double-check your usage of TempWorkflowClientExternalFactory vs TempClientExternalFactory? I just realized we haven't been consistent in either the question or the answer.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, Sorry for the typo. I have rectified in the code above (however left the error the original inject of TempWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl as is so ensure question continuity). I trying to bind TempWorkflowClientExternalFactory.

Comment: Hi @Jeff, I am trying to inject TempWorkflowClientExternalFactory. It is similar to GreeterWorkflowClientExternalFactory found [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/getting-started-example-helloworldworkflow.html here] (last code snippet of the page). Just providing this, if at all it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

PS: This is the first time I am using Guice.

I tried to reproduce the issue. But I couldn't. Here is my complete code. Let me know if I am doing something different.

**TempClientExternalFactory**

```
public interface TempClientExternalFactory {
  public TempWorkflowClientExternal getClient(String in);
}
```

**TempClientExternalFactoryImpl**

```
public class TempClientExternalFactoryImpl implements TempClientExternalFactory {

  public TempClientExternalFactoryImpl(String swf_service, String domain) {

  }

  public TempWorkflowClientExternal getClient(String in) {
    return new TempWorkflowClientExternal();
  }
}
```

**TempWorkflowClientExternal**

```
public class TempWorkflowClientExternal {
  public void callWorkflowMethod() {
    System.out.println("In callWorkflowMethod");
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.name.Named;

class Test {

  @Inject
  @Named("ABC")
  TempClientExternalFactory fac;

  public void method() {
    TempWorkflowClientExternal temp = fac.getClient("123");
    temp.callWorkflowMethod();
    System.out.println("Success");
   }
}
```

**TestModule**

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.name.Names;

public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    TempClientExternalFactory fac = new TempClientExternalFactoryImpl(null, null);
    bind(TempClientExternalFactory.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("ABC")).toInstance(fac);
  }
}
```

**App**

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TestModule());
    Test app = injector.getInstance(Test.class);
    app.method();
  }
}
```

Also, this stackoverflow question looks similar to what you have asked;

[Error in binding: No implementation was bound - Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611635/error-in-binding-no-implementation-was-bound-guice)

Comment: TempClientExternalFactory, TempWorkflowClientExternal, TempClientExternalFactoryImpl are all auto-generated classes/interfaces by AWS-SWF. You cannot define these classes or modify them.

Comment: I think I was able to get past this...by using `@Inject TempClientExternalFactoryImpl`  instead of the interface... However I am getting an when I call fac.getClient()... I will investigate this more... If the two issues are not related I will post my finding as an answer

Comment: I am using the @Named annotations at both places. I even tried without the annotation. In case when no annotation is used, it binds the wrong object